# Does ITextTemplatingEngineHost depends on VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, t4

I want to build application on MVC, that will get template text and generate code like T4, but I don't want to depend on VisualStudio, I mean I don't want to install VisualStudio on the server where my application will be running. Of course, I'll install Dot.Net Framework on the server but **NOT** VisualStudio.

I read, that I need to implement ITextTemplatingEngineHost, but to do this I need to reference

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0

2 questions:

1. Does this DLLs come with VisualStudio or with Dot.Net Framework?
2. If it comes with VisualStudio, can I put 2 DLLs in BIN folder, implement Custom HOST and deploy my application to the server where NO VisualStudio is installed and my application will use all the functionality of this DLLs?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4 isn't designed/tested to be used on the server other than in low volume build server scenarios.

The binaries you mention are only supplied as part of Visual Studio and the product license does not permit them to be deployed other than by installing Visual Studio. (Other than to build servers for the purpose of automating solution build)

Comment: Can you please advise some GOOD open source or other alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

T4 is for generating files.

If your intent is to create self modifying or dynamic code at runtime, you shouldn't care about files.

You can use reflection to build objects dynamically.

Google will help you find resources, like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec